# How to tunnel HTTP over SSH via SOCKS?

Tags: linux, ssh, proxy, socks-proxy

This should be a simple issue to solve, but for some reason it's not working for me.

`ssh vps` works just fine (I use authentication keys)

I set up the tunnel with the command:

`ssh -C2TNv -D 8080 vps`

I then modify Firefox network settings:

- manual config

  - http proxy: localhost, port: 8080
  - use this proxy server for all protocols
  - SOCKS v5
- about:config

  - network.proxy.socks_remote_dns: true

Terminal output:

```
$ ssh -C2TNv -D 8080 vps
OpenSSH_6.0p1, OpenSSL 1.0.1a 19 Apr 2012
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/ting/.ssh/config
debug1: /home/ting/.ssh/config line 47: Applying options for vps
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Connecting to vps.server.com [1.1.1.1] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/ting/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /home/ting/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.5p1 Debian-6+squeeze1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.5p1 Debian-6+squeeze1 pat OpenSSH_5*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.0
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 zlib@openssh.com
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 zlib@openssh.com
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA <removed>
debug1: Host 'vps.server.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/ting/.ssh/known_hosts:10
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/ting/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 279
debug1: Enabling compression at level 6.
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to vps.server.com ([1.1.1.1]:22).
debug1: Local connections to LOCALHOST:8080 forwarded to remote address socks:0
debug1: Local forwarding listening on ::1 port 8080.
debug1: channel 0: new [port listener]
debug1: Local forwarding listening on 127.0.0.1 port 8080.
debug1: channel 1: new [port listener]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
```

I then try visiting a site using Firefox, SSH output:

```
debug1: Connection to port 8080 forwarding to socks port 0 requested.
debug1: channel 2: new [dynamic-tcpip]
debug1: channel 2: free: dynamic-tcpip, nchannels 3
debug1: Connection to port 8080 forwarding to socks port 0 requested.
debug1: channel 2: new [dynamic-tcpip]
debug1: channel 2: free: dynamic-tcpip, nchannels 3
```

Despite the proxy seemingly working, visiting any site with Firefox just returns with the error "The connection was reset".

Comment: have you tried curl. $curl --socks4 127.0.0.1:8080 http://blah

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Your SSH command with -D is fine  (so the SOCKS will tunnel it's just the connecting to the SOCKS via HTTP, that you have to sort out)

I get good output with

```
curl --socks5 127.0.0.1:8080 http://blah
```

but I get the same wrong output you get if I do

```
 curl --proxy 127.0.0.1:8080 http://blah
```

So, firefox is connecting as if it's an HTTP Proxy

Looking at the firefox window

manual config YES

you said you ticked "use this proxy server for all protocols"
That is a totally wrong move! You want to enter a SOCKS proxy, and if you do that then the SOCKS box get nulled/greyed out and you can only enter an HTTP Proxy.

So don't tick that.

And do, enter the socks proxy ip.

and remove where it says no proxy for 127.0.0.1,localhost  .  if it says that, which is default.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However I got it working by clearing out **everything** in Firefox's proxy config screen *except* the `SOCKS Host` field. If I added anything into the `HTTP Proxy` field it stopped working.

Comment: @wting or @barlop, I couldn't ask for a description of the ssh flags `-C2TN` could I?

Comment: @MikeH-R  i'm not that familiar with it but it'd break down to -C2 -T -N -v. looking at man ssh, it looks like -C2 is to do with compression -C does compression and it mentions inclusion of a level so eg. -C2 which he did.   -T or -N or both -T and -N are to do with making the ssh simpler in the sense that, normally when you ssh even with port forwarding, it opens a cmd prompt and you have a shell so what he did there stops that from happening so he just has the port forwarding feature he wants without the shell.  and -v is verbose. (though if you want verbose  -vvv i.e. 3 of them is better)

Comment: Thanks @barlop, you cleared it up a little from the docs, much appreciated.

Comment: @MikeH-R no prob I was wondering at the time what that was too though didn't check at the time! I was still curious when I looked it up now!

Answer (score 1):

To check connection via curl you may also use flags `-I -v` (to get only HTTP headers and to get output more talkative).

If these flags selected and curl connecting - you'll see in output string like:

```
* Rebuilt URL to: http://www.google.ru/
*   Trying ::1...
* 87
* 245
* 198
* 44
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 8080 (#0)
```

If cannot get connection:

```
* Rebuilt URL to: http://www.google.ru/
*   Trying ::1...
* connect to ::1 port 8080 failed: Connection refused
```

In another terminal's tab with ssh connection you'll something like this:

```
debug1: channel 2: new [dynamic-tcpip]
debug1: channel 2: free: direct-tcpip: listening port 9999 for 87.245.198.44 port 80, connect from ::1 port 55034 to ::1 port 8080, nchannels 3
```